# Grunt synchronous task running with grunt-shell and grunt-ssh

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, ssh, gruntjs

I'm having a hell of a time trying to finish up a deploy script I'm running. It works maybe half the time, and it's frustrating, because I'm using mostly code I haven't written. I'm really hoping there's a lower-level workaround I can execute.

Essentially what's happening is I'm trying to do 5 tasks that end up happening asynchronously. There doesn't appear to be a sound way to block them. Those are

1. A static file build/compile process
2. A compression process
3. An ftp delivery process
4. An uncompress process
5. A permissions management and relinking process

Sometimes the compress process happens midway through the build/compile process, sometimes the ftp delivery fails, sometimes the relinking process attempts to link to a folder on the receiving end that doesn't exist yet, and fails.

Has anyone had any success using grunt for a deployment process? What are some tips I can use to get around this bullshit? It's totally ruining me.

Answer (score 0):

Try shelljs - https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs

Its commands run synchronously. I've used it in a grunt task before for the same reason.

Comment: There's no support for remote scripting. My biggest problems are with executing scripts on the remote server; locally, it seems like it blocks just fine.